# Need queue type data structure for store string ids

Tags: java

We have a scenario that need to store limited number of string ids.normally 30.
We have following conditions.

1. If some one add 31 one then need to remove the oldest one and add
   the new one.
2. If some one add a same id need to remove oldest one and add new one to the top.

Currently Guava has EvictingQueue.But do not know it should allow duplicates.If duplicate comes need to remove oldest one and add new one to the top

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: LinkedHashMap there for limiting.But it is a map type one.I need a List type one.

Comment: 1 and 2 appear to be the same...? That is, when you add a string, remove it if it exists, and then add the string to the top of the structure. Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly then an implementation of
`java.util.Deque` (`java.util.ArrayDequeue` for example) might be what you are looking for. It's a 'double ended' Queue and allows you to push/pop elements at both ends. So you could use '`addFirst`' to put a new Element into the dequeue and '`removeLast`' to remove the oldest element.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a school project but I advise only something about this topic.

Find Queue algorithm on Wikipedia and implement this in Java. Use pop and push methdods.

For second, use iteration on queue and update value.

Comment: I am asking what is the current implementations we have like Guava project.Do we have such ones.